# Request validation imposes validation code duplication in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

Say I have a REST API method creating a user. I also have a user entity with configured validation constraints. The question is how to validate the data from the request. My problems are:

1. I can't populate a user instance without validating the data in the request beforehand - some data might be missing in it, other might be invalid. For example `null` passed to a user entity's setter with `string` type-hinting.
2. I'm not so keen to validate the request data separately, before populating a user instance, because it would be a duplication of the validation constraints configured for the user entity. It would be a problem to manage the same or similar validation constrains in two places - the controller and the entity validation config.

So basically I want to avoid the duplication of the validation constraints in the code and the config, but at the same time I'm forced to duplicate it  before populating the entity. How can I get over this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite physiologic.

What I would suggest is to use a DTO where no restrictions are checked (basically where you can accept "all kind of data" in your setters or even by having public properties that is less cumbersome) and to have a validation on it.

When the DTO is valid, create the underlying object in a valid state (Value Object?)

Of course you need to "duplicate" some constraints but I would not consider this as a *real* duplication because, actually, DTO and underlying object *are not the same object* even if them seems to be related. If you disagree - and it could be the case - just stop and think about the boost you'll have by decoupling entity (that should be *always* in a valid state) from the model where user input data are taken.

Comment: This is how it should be done, no more entities in forms. Kudos.

Comment: I have a DTO used for responses from my service, but I haven't thought of using it at the input. So what you mean is to convert a request to a DTO, then validate this DTO using a separately described constraints, then use it to create a user instance?

Comment: @Sergey yes, that's basically the idea

Comment: @DonCallisto would you happen to know of any guides online that would demonstrate your answer for new beginners like me.  Trying to get a visual understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @klewis the only resource I can remember (even if is not strictly about same topic but a similar one) is [this](https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/)